# Change column property to id from other table

Tags: mysql

So I have 1 table named articles and 1 named categories.

- In articles table I have column categoryName which is for example 'culture'.
- In categories table I have columns id and name.

I want to change categoryName from **articles** table to id from **categories** table where **articles** categoryName = **categories** name.

I want to do this in phpmyadmin SQL tab so I don't need to do this manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you right then try this:

```
UPDATE articles a, categories c
SET a.categoryName = c.id
WHERE a.categoryName = c.name;
```